# Simple Contour Integral on Rectangle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am having trouble finding a full solution to this contour integral, as I cannot use Cauchy's Theorem on it, or residue theorem that is.

$$\int_\gamma{\frac{\bar{z}}{8+z}}$$

where $\gamma$ is a rectangle w/ verticies $\pm3$ and $\pm i$ oriented clockwise

I tried using the parametrzation of $-3t + i$ and $3t + i, -1\leq{t}\leq{1}$, but now I don't now where to go from here!

Comment: First draw a diagram of the rectangle.  You will find that it's not a rectangle :) but never mind.  Then you will have to parametrise each side separately.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I guess that you need to add $dz$ inside the integral, and that the rectangle is defined by the points $3+ i,3-i,-3+i,-3-i$. Just parametrize the contour, by example note that, by definition, $dz=d(x+iy)=dx+idy$, now compute the line integral using the change of variable $z=x+iy$.